# Information need to pass to another thread

Tags: c++, sockets

I am a newbie programmer in linux domain. I am basically a MicroController programmer familiar with C. Now I am into little PC programing and need some inputs.

I am opening a socket and sending a Broadcast looking for my **Embedded device** on network. First I am probing the interfaces on the machine and will be broadcasting in each subnet, a call to my device with a signature. The device is listening on that particular port and it responds with its signature. The program then gets the ip and other details of my device and will start communicating.
I am sending a call in one function in each interface and to avoid blocking I am creating another listening thread to get response which may take some time to arrive. On receiving response I need to inform other thread about this and data to be given to them.
In this scenario, which is the best method to do that? Signal, Message or flag or whatever?
Since I need to implement this code in windows also, it will be good if it is possible to use a mechanism which is possible in both platforms.
Please suggest
Roy Thomas

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone: ... (it made me smile, but...)

Answer (score 0):

It is a classic network programming issue. Personally, when I do network programming at this level in C++ , I use the C++ POCO libraries (see [this](http://pocoproject.org/)).

You do not specify whether you use UDP or TCP. If you use TCP, the library provides something called *TCPServer framework* that deals with these issues, i.e. managing a pool of worker threads that deals with connections.

[These slides](http://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf), starting at slide "The TCPServer Framework", explain the principle.

Then you can use FIFO to communicate between your threads or POCO libraries notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Qt Creator its a cross platform C++ IDE it has very good implementation for signals and slots.

Its got its own library of functions that extend the STL and some very nice threading ones that you should take a look at.

I know this may not have been the answer you were looking for but i use Qt every day and its great! so feel free to ask any questions ...